# Term Store implementation

Tags: term-store

I am building a site for the IT company I work for, so far I have created the following sites within my site collection:

Home Site - (Top Level site)

1. CLIENT INFO (Subsite)
2. EMPLOYEE  (Subsite)
3. IMPACT - Company department (Subsite)
4. INTERNAL SYSTEMS  (Subsite)
5. PROJECTS - Company department (Subsite)
6. TSM - Company department  (Subsite)

I have information about our clients, Passwords, Client documents, client Visio diagrams etc
Also company internal systems, new employee onboarding documents and info etc

I am looking at implementing the term store but not really sure what terms to create and the structure

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee519604(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I was hoping for some specific advice to my situation

Comment: I know, but the terms should reflect your organization, how you work and what kind of information that is mandatory to keep your data structured. While you can only get some general advice's from here about what possibly could be useful to you, the only way to identify terms is to look how your company works today. Many corporations spends weeks doing this to build a taxonomy that reflect their needs.

Comment: A good start could be Year tags, Month tags, document categories, cities, clients, business processes, products, departments etc.

Comment: Ok thanks, do I create all the terms for the top level site and all subsites from the term store management at the top level or do I have to create the terms at each subsite level?

Comment: No, you can either create a global term set that is available to all the web applications that uses the same Manage Metadata services, or you can go to a specific site collection > site settings and select "Term Store Management". Click here and you will see an additional folder with the site collection name. Any Term-group created in this folder will only be available to the current site collection.